# How does scaling rows to sum to 1, of a positive matrix change the perron vector?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Reposting from [math.sx](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1468447/how-does-scaling-rows-to-sum-to-1-of-a-positive-matrix-change-the-perron-vector) due to lack of response. Let $A$ be a $N\times N$ positive matrix such that $A_{ij}>0$. By Perron-Frobenius theorem, there is a unique positive **left** eigenvector called Perron vector $x$ corresponding to the largest eigenvalue and also it sums to 1. Call it  $x$. Let $D$ be a diagonal matrix such that $B=DA$ is a stochastic matrix with rows summing to 1. Call $y$ the Perron vector of $B$. How are $x$ and $y$ related?

Comment: 1) Can you edit in a link to the m.se question? 2) Have you tried doing this in detail for $N=2$ to see what happens there?

Comment: 1) Link is added 2) Yes, I should be doing that first!!. Thanks.

Comment: I am afraid that the reason why you got no answer on math.se is because there is no simple relation between them.

Comment: A minimal remark: Wlog you can always assume that $A$ is the adjacency matrix of a weighted, undirected graph and then $D$ is the matrix of its (weighed, directed) degrees. I agree with @FedericoPoloni that there should be no simple relation between these Perron eigenvectors, but perhaps this graph approach might give you some keywords to look after.

Comment: Yes, I will take a look. Isn't it a directed graph since $\mathbf{A}$ may or may not be symmetric?